# How to get time from PostgreSQL in the same TZ, which was initialy used while uploading to DB, instead of UTC?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime

1. There are datetimes that are uploaded to DB by Django in the format “2015-10-31 17:00:00+03” (aware form of time).
2. PostgreSQL keeps time in UTC
3. In pgAdmin I see my datetimes as “2015-10-31 17:00:00+03” instead of UTC.

Is it possible to get from DB “2015-10-31 17:00:00+03” instead of “2015-10-31 14:00:00+00”? As I understand, if datetime is aware, there is TZ info in the value in DB, but how to take this TZ?

---

For example, I want to upload a new datetimes, but before to write to DB, I want to compare these datetimes with the values ​​that already exist in the database. So, a new part of datetimes have format:

“2015-10-31 17:00:00+03”, but the values ​​are taken from the database is UTC, ie

“2015-10-31 14:00:00+00”, when it should be also 17:00:00+03!

How to get value from DB not in UTC, but in TZ +3 (for this example)?

```
test = Shows.objects.get(name = 'Test')
test.date_time  # I get UTC, but I need to get it as TZ +3
```

PS: hardcoding like this

```
from pytz import timezone
right_time = utc_from_db.astimezone(timezone('Europe/Berlin'))
```

is impossible. It is necessary to get exactly the time zone from the database that was originally filled with a value, because all datetimes ​​may have different time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was informed, seems it is impossible. PostgreSQL uses TZ from awared type of time to convert time to UTC and can't be converted back natively.

If I want to get back UTC-ed time from DB to the time with TZ it was initially, I can make one more column in DB and put there the name of TZ, such as 'Europe/Berlin' and convert time from DB with UTC to initial time with proper TZ  like this (the same code as in the question part):

```
from pytz import timezone
right_time = utc_from_db.astimezone(timezone('Europe/Berlin'))
```